# Put text under cursor in edittext from java

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I have got a two EditText in activity. I need after some event put text in current position of cursor. How can I do that?

Comment: That's the shortest question I've ever seen.
can you provide more info?

Comment: Ok, I have two edittext, user can move cursor in them. After button pressed I need to insert some string into this edittext under cursor. What additional informational you need?

Comment: So only when User focuses on a TextView you want the string to appear in it ?

Comment: yes, I need do that after button pressed

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please insert the code that you have tried so far, into your original question, not in another comment.

Answer (score 0):

```
    et1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            et1.setText("myString");
        }
    });
```

et1 is your edit text, do it for the second EditText either.

Comment: ok, I need to edit previos text, just insert some addition string to edittext

Comment: like et1.setText(et1.getText()+"myString"); ?

Comment: et1.setText(et1.getText()+"myString");

et1.setSelection(et1.getText().length());